# Insert same html into element multiple times with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the user to click on a button and then have some html pop into an element. I did so and it works but it only works once. If they click the button again, nothing happens. I thought using empty() would fix the problem but it doesn't. What's wrong with my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready( function() {

   $('#button').on('click', function () {

     $('#ul').html('<li>testing testing</li>').hide(1000, function() {

        $(this).empty();    

     });    

   });

});

</script>

<input type="button" value="click me" id="button" />

<ul id="ul">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is hidden the second time you click the button. You can do:

```
$('#ul').show().html('...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KXkgZ/

Comment: Is there a way I could target the newly inserted li in the ul and just hide that? Actually I think I can do that on my own.

Comment: I don’t understand your comment, sorry :) If you have another question, it’s probably better to post a new topic.

Comment: @jason328 using your current method, you are replacing the ul content with your li each time so there is only one at any given time

Comment: @Huangism yes, that is how I interpreted "*pop some html into an element*".

Comment: @David sorry my comment was meant for the OP's comment

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#button").click(function(){ 
    $("#ul").append("testing testing");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

as you want to pop html each time you click on button you should use `append`

```
$('#ul').append('<li>testing testing</li>');
```

see [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('<li>testing testing</li>').appendTo('#ul').hide(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();    
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a .hide() you set the CSS selector "display" = "NONE" You need to change it to something like this:

```
$('#ul').html('<li>testing testing</li>').hide(1000, function() {
  $(this).empty();
  $(this).show();
});
```